# Getter Pattern Within Class?

Tags: java, private, encapsulation, getter

I have a field in a class that should only be accessed directly from a getter. As an example...

```
public class CustomerHelper {
  private final Integer customerId;
  private String customerName_ = null;

  public CustomerHelper(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
  }

  public String getCustomerName() {
    if(customerName_ == null){
      // Get data from database.
      customerName_ = customerDatabase.readCustomerNameFromId(customerId);
      // Maybe do some additional post-processing, like casting to all uppercase.
      customerName_ = customerName_.toUpperCase();
    }
    return customerName_;
  }

  public String getFormattedCustomerInfo() {
    return String.format("%s: %s", customerId, getCustomerName());
  }
}
```

So even within the class itself a function like getFormattedCustomerInfo should not be able to access it via customerName_. Is there a way to enforce a class not access a field directly aside from the provided getter function?

Comment: Even private class members are accessible within a class, so I don't see a direct way of doing this.  Maybe you could move `getFormattedCustomerInfo` to a separate util class.  Why do you need this?

Comment: No. A class has always access to all its attributes. Only possibility would be to set the class abstract and write a concrete class, which would have to use the getter since the attribute is set `private`. Two remarks: - In Java, it is unusual to wirte an underscore at the end of attributes - The [`Formattable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html) would be the proper way to add the functionality you want to your class.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to do this, but a hackish way is to hoist the fields to a supertype and expose it via a `protected` or `public` getter.  Other than that, I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to cache the database value, and want to protect against accessing a value which has yet to be cached.

If this is true,  then the variable `customerName_` should not exist in the `CustomerHelper` class; the cached value should exist closer to the database.

The method `customerDatabase.readCustomerNameFromId(customerId)` should first look at a cache, and if the cache is empty, call the database and cache the result.

Effectively, `customerName_` becomes a value in the cache: `Map<Integer, String> cache` where the key is `customerId`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such mechanism in Java (or at least I think there should not be). If you are sure that `getFormattedCustomerInfo` should be prohibited from direct access to `customerName_`, create another class and compose them.

I would recommend `CustomerInfoFormatter`.

Also, I would change `customerName_` to `customerName` as the language supports privacy by explicit declaration and it is not needed to add more indicators.

Comment: "*Also, I would change customerName_ to _customerName to indicate its privacy.*" - In Java, you normally do neither the one nor the other.

Comment: I am a Python developer, so it looked normal to me, but you are right, the language supports it by explicit declaration. You can suggest an edit.